# django query set : retrieving/extracting objects with different primary keys (from a list)

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to get to grips with django, and I am having trouble retrieving objects with primary keys, which come from another list. So, I am able to do the following:

```
one_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
```

this seems fine - no problems. Now, I have a list of pk's like so:

```
pk_id=[1,5,10,200,300,310]
```

I would like to extract the objects with the above `pk`s (looping?) and make the into a `single queryset`. I am not sure looping is the best option - was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to collect the objects with pk's from the list and return a single resulting queryset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_id)
```

Comment: Jeez! yet to try this - but is this documented anywhere? Went through the entire docs with no luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! Accepted your answer.

Comment: Quick follow up question on this - does `Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_id)` not follow the order of iteration w.r.t list pk_id?

Comment: by default it should be probably be taking the elements in their natural ordering, since pk_id's are sequential, they should already be ordered, but you can chain order_by('pk') to be sure.

Comment: well, I would like the order in `pk_id` to be maintained. So, for example, my `pk_id=[264, 282, 259, 262, 268, 270, 99, 203, 293, 284]` and I do: `Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_id).order_by('pk')` but this does not seem to maintain the order as in `pk_id`.

Comment: And what if i want to make a query in which i want to extract many elements using their primary key and i also want to check a condition.like i have a list of primary keys and i want to get all the elements with level > 3. in this case what will be the query